# Concatenating lists in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading [Dive into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/native-datatypes.html) and at the section of lists, the author states that you can concatenate lists with the "+" operator or calling the extend() method. Are these the same just two different ways to do the operation? Any reason I should be using one or the other?

```
>>> a_list = a_list + [2.0, 3]
>>> a_list.extend([2.0, 3])
```

Comment: overridden `+` operator gives the result in another list, it's not an in-place addition. Whereas, extend is an in-place modification to the list.. The usage should be primarily on your logic, and probably on the size of your list...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`a_list.extend(b_list)` modifies `a_list` in place. `a_list = a_list + b_list` creates a new list, then saves it to the name `a_list`. Note that `a_list += b_list` should be exactly the same as the `extend` version.

Using `extend` or `+=` is probably slightly faster, since it doesn't need to create a new object, but if there's another reference to `a_list` around, it's value will be changed too (which may or may not be desirable).

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, I have defined 3 functions for each of the three ways to concatenate 2 lists. Note that func1 and func3 , both modify list1 when you print it after calling either of the functions. While, when you call func2, and then you print list1, it remains the same as before.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


def func1(a_list, b_list):
    (a_list.extend(b_list))
    return(a_list)


def func2(a_list, b_list):
    a_list = a_list + b_list
    return (a_list)


def func3(a_list, b_list):
    a_list += b_list
    return (a_list)



print(func2(list1, list2))  #does not change list1   
print(list1)       # list1 is different from return value of func3
```

But with any of the calls below:

1. print(func3(list1, list2))
   print(list1)   #list1 is same as the return value of func3
2. print(func1(list1, list2))
   print(list1)  #list1 is same as the return value of func1

Comment: The examples are correct, however, it doesn't help to understand the original question. By adding functions, the question will be related to the scope of the variables too. `print(func2(list1, list2))` prints the function variable of `a_list` which is the output of func2, and a different variable than `list1`.  If you want to get a similar result, you may write something like `list1 = func2(list1, list2)`; which saves the function output to `list1`.